# How to handle and report patient characteristic statistic with missing data in essay?

Tags: missing-data, descriptive-statistics

I'm now working on an clinical trial essay with some doctors. When generating patient characteristic statistic form, I found basic patient characteristic data has some missing.

The missing datas are in features like "whether patient had hypertension" or "average blood pressure on exam". The missing rates are from 2% to 50%. We don't have a way to re-collect those data and they must be reported in essay.

Patient characteristic statistics are important evidence to prove efficience of experiment so we can't just remove statistic with missing data from the report table.

I know multiple ways to fill NAs in machine learning task and just report missing rates in ETL task. But how should I deal with missing data like that in an essay?

Thank you